How to Send JSON Input to Azure Cognitive Services Translation API Using Azure Client Libraries?
I'm using Azure Cognitive Services for text translation and need to send data in the following JSON format:
data = [{"text":"Good Morning"},{"text":"Good night"}]

When I use the Azure REST API directly, I can successfully send this input, and it works as expected. However, when I try to send the same data using the Azure client libraries, I'm unable to do so.
Is there a way to send this specific JSON input using Azure client libraries for translation? If so, what would be the correct method to achieve this?
#This is my code.

from azure.ai.translation.text import TextTranslationClient

client = TextTranslationClient(endpoint, credential)
result = client.translate(to=["de"], input=data)

when i execute this it gives me error - string index out of range


How to Send JSON Input to Azure Cognitive Services Translation API Using Azure Client Libraries?

The error occurs when you try to access a character in a string using an index that's outside the valid range. In a string, indexes start at "0" and go up to one less than the total number of characters in the string.
Error:
In my environment, I got the same error when accessing the response with particular range (out of index).

I tried with below code and got the expected results successfully with Json input format.
Code:
import os
import json
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.translation.text import TextTranslationClient

key = "xxxxxxx0"
region="eastus"

credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
text_translator = TextTranslationClient(credential=credential, region=region)
to_language = ["de"]
data = [{"text":"Good Morning"},{"text":"Good night"}]

response = text_translator.translate(body=data, to_language=to_language)
if response:
    for translation in response:
        for translation_text in translation.translations:
            print(translation_text.text)

Output:
Guten Morgen
Gute Nacht


Reference:
Azure Text Translation client library for Python | Microsoft Learn
